# ArcGIS online: Job aborted, approached out-of-memory threshold

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm attempting to download the [Output Areas dataset](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/output-area-december-2011-full-extent-boundaries-in-england-and-wales) for England. I'm trying to download the the shapefile for all of the Output Areas in the dataset.

When I press 'Download,' then 'Shapefile,' the downloading animation never finishes. If I look at the 'Network' tab of Chrome developer tools, then look at the response of the request for `https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/09b8a48426e3482ebbc0b0c49985c0fb_1.zip?outSR=%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A27700%2C%22wkid%22%3A27700%7D&url_only=true` I see this:

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"message":"Export job failed: error: Job aborted, approached out-of-memory threshold","code":500}}
```

So I think the server is running out of memory, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Can I avoid this out-of-memory error somehow, (e.g. by only downloading a tenth of the data at a time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataset you want appears to be a mega dataset (compared to the generalized dataset anyways). The Open Data process requires the data to be streamed from the host server to the Open Data server where it assembles it into a shapefile (or whatever format you've chosen). Unfortunately you can't "fix" that.

You can however download the data in chunks. It'd be on you to figure out how to merge the many shapefiles into 1 (if that's what you need)

The Open Data website allows you to grab filtered parts (chunks) of the dataset. Steps as shown in the below image:

- Navigate to the **Data** tab
- Click the **filter icon** beside an attribute. ObjectID is an easy way as they look to be sequential.
- Add start and end values. I attempted a couple chunks of 10,000 and that seemed to work well. About 25mb shapefiles.
- From the **Download** option, make sure you use the **Filtered Dataset**

The alternative to using the filter is to zoom the map in. The map can act as a filter as well. Note - once you've changed the map extent at all, the Filtered option now takes into account the location and this impacts the filter. So if you don't want the map filter, you made need to reload your page.

[image]